# Getting Magento translation done completely

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to figure out the translation in the magento.
Ok, so I understand how it works but here is the problem.

For instance this is part of the source code in one of the PHTML files:

```
<p class="hello"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Hello, %s!', $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomerName())) ?></strong></p>
```

How am i supposed to translate the word "Hello," in this case? Theres tons of this type of parsend strings on the page and please dont tell me that i will have to re-write all this examples to get the translator working?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento will translate the literal string that is placed in the `__()` function. Meaning, if you place this in your translation file it will translate anything placed with `%s`:

`"Hello, %s!","Bonjour, %s!"`

As for actually translating, you can use inline translation (found in `System > Configuration > Developer`) or adjust your themes custom translation file. If you have caching enabled, don't forget to refresh the Translation cache type in `System > Configuration > Cache Management`.

Comment: Hello Yrcrz! Thanks for the explanation. Well, went with translate.csv file inside app frontend folder, so I am just writting the csv manualy. Its those parsed strings that confused me, but i think i get the point now. The only hard work that needs to be done is to use "?php echo $this->__" if not used and then it should all go smoothly ... i guess?